# NameError: global name not defined using exec

Tags: python, exec, global

I have a small code

```
def MyFunc2(x):
    return x + 1
def MyFunc3(a):
    return MyFunc2(7)

res = str(MyFunc3(1))
```

It work without problem in stand alone, but if I tried to use it with exec

```
code = """
def MyFunc2(x):
    return x + 1
def MyFunc3(a):
    return MyFunc2(7)

res = str(MyFunc3(1))

"""
exec code
```

I have the error " NameError: global name 'MyFunc2' is not defined "
What is wrong with this code ?

A working code

```
        code="""
def MyFunc3(a):
    def MyFunc2(x):
        return x + 1

    return MyFunc2(7)

res = str(MyFunc3(1))

"""

        exec (code)
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe in your editor you have some bad code lying around that is raising that?

Comment: Works fine for me. Try running `exec(code)`

Comment: No change with exec(code), I have found a working code (I have edited the first post), but I can't understand why the first one don't work.